# JQ: Removing null values from a JSON array in jq

Tags: json, jq

Still I can't figure out how to remove null values from a key of JSON array type.
I need an empty key({}) if all the values are null or remove nulls from the JSON array.
In the below example, I want to filter the nulls from Workloads JSON array. Please let me know any workaround . Thanks a lot.
[ I am using jq version 1.5 ]
For example, with this input:

```
{
  "EC2 Instance Metadata": [
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-1",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.2.3.4",
      "Workloads": [
        null
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-1"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "container"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image/1.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-2",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.2.3.44",
      "Workloads": [
        null
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-2"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "container-2"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image/2.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-3",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.23.3.44",
      "Workloads": [
        "workload-1",
        "workload-2",
        "workload-3",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "workload-4"
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-1",
        "pod-2"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "cnt-1",
        "cnt-2"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image-1",
        "image-2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want this output :-

```
{
  "EC2 Instance Metadata": [
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-1",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.2.3.4",
      "Workloads": [
        {}
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-1"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "container"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image/1.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-2",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.2.3.44",
      "Workloads": [
        {}
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-2"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "container-2"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image/2.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-3",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.23.3.44",
      "Workloads": [
        "workload-1",
        "workload-2",
        "workload-3",
        "workload-4"
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-1",
        "pod-2"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "cnt-1",
        "cnt-2"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image-1",
        "image-2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Tried almost all the hints mentioned [Here](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/104), but no luck.

Comment: What determines whether a `null` will be removed without replacement or just turned into an empty object `{}` (both cases occur in your sample)?

Comment: Thanks @pmf for quick response. Yes, both cases occur in my sample. If the value is only null then replace it with  {} and if its mix of valid values and null, then just exclude null and keep remaining values as it is.

Comment: What if the array contains more than one but nothing but `null` values, e.g. `[null, null, null]`?

Comment: it will be simply an empty key with `{}` if all values are null.

Comment: could you make the example even longer? /s. to remove null values from an array: `jq -n '[1, null] | map(select(. != null))'`

Answer (score 2):

This recursively (`..`) reduces `arrays` containing (also) `values` (anything but `null`) to only contain those `values`, otherwise (containing nothing but `null`) it replaces them with `[{}]`:

```bash
jq '(.. | arrays) |= if any(values) then map(values) else [{}] end'
```

```json
{
  "EC2 Instance Metadata": [
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-1",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.2.3.4",
      "Workloads": [
        {}
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-1"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "container"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image/1.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-2",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.2.3.44",
      "Workloads": [
        {}
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-2"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "container-2"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image/2.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-3",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.23.3.44",
      "Workloads": [
        "workload-1",
        "workload-2",
        "workload-3",
        "workload-4"
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-1",
        "pod-2"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "cnt-1",
        "cnt-2"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image-1",
        "image-2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6FKhOb3TWK9)

Comment: OP needs an `[ {} ]` if there is 1 `null` in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If we loop over the `Workload` we can use the update assignment ([`|=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=)) and an [`if`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else) to:

1. Use [`all(. == null)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#all,all(condition),all(generator;condition)) to check if all values are `null`, if so, replace with `[ {} ]`
2. Otherwise, use [`map(values)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#arrays,objects,iterables,booleans,numbers,normals,finites,strings,nulls,values,scalars) to only keep values that are not `null`

```
."EC2 Instance Metadata"[].Workloads |= 
    if all(. == null) 
        then [ {} ] 
        else map(values)
    end
```

---

Will give the following output, which you can [try in this online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/bZhAy475-87)

```json
{
  "EC2 Instance Metadata": [
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-1",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.2.3.4",
      "Workloads": [
        {}
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-1"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "container"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image/1.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-2",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.2.3.44",
      "Workloads": [
        {}
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-2"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "container-2"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image/2.0"
      ]
    },
    {
      "EC2 Private IPv4 DNS Name": "compute.internal-3",
      "EC2 Private IPv4 address": "1.23.3.44",
      "Workloads": [
        "workload-1",
        "workload-2",
        "workload-3",
        "workload-4"
      ],
      "Application Pods": [
        "pod-1",
        "pod-2"
      ],
      "Application Containers": [
        "cnt-1",
        "cnt-2"
      ],
      "Container Images": [
        "image-1",
        "image-2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have required reputations for upvote. I am new to this community. Hence please let me know if there any other way to upvote. Appreciate your help!